# UIWebview: How to place an icon before a html link and highlight both on tap

Tags: html, ios, css, objective-c, uiwebview

In an iOS UIWebview I have the problem, that I need to prefix standalone links located in a locally loaded html file by an icon. Both must be highlighted when I tap the link. The icon should be highlighted by replacing a non-active version by an active one. The result should look like:

[image: link prefixed by arrow icon]

Comment: Why is this question iOS-related? The behavior in UIWebview differs from the one in a normal browser?

Comment: Of course the behaviour even differs between different iOS versions or between different Webkit versions. Additionally finger input differs from mouse input. So 'hover' behaves differently.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily I found a working solution:

HTML

```
<a href="http://www.google.de" class="standalone-link">
  <div class="standalone_link_background">
    <div class="standalone_link_icon">
        <div class="standalone_link_text">Google</div>
    </div>
  </div>;
</a>
```

CSS

```
/* unvisited, visited, mouse over, selected link */
a, a:link, a:visited, a:hover
{
    color:                          #00f;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); /* disable gray flash in webview */
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

a:active
{
    color:                          #f00;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); /* disable gray flash in webview */
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

a.standalone-link, a.standalone-link:link, a.standalone-link:visited, a.standalone-link:hover
{
    color:                          #ffffff;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); /* disable gray flash in webview */
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

a.standalone-link:active
{
    color:                          #f00;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); /* disable gray flash in webview */
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

div.standalone_link_icon
{
    background:                     url('link_icon.png') no-repeat left;
    width:                          20pt; /* something big is okay so the arrow is not cut fro the right side */
    height:                         12pt; /* set the height of the icon */
}

div.standalone_link_icon:active
{
    background:                     url('link_icon_highlight.png') no-repeat left;
}

div.standalone_link_text
{
    margin-left:                    14pt;
    width:                          9999pt; /* Standalone links shouldn't be wider than the display width */
    float:                          left;
}

div.standalone_link_background
{
    background-color:               rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    clear:                          left;
}
```

Can this be done shorter or somehow better? Comments and improvements appreciated ;-)